# mysqli update function deletes table content

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm quite new to coding mysqli in general and have a problem I can't solve on my own:

I have created an insert, delete and update page. Insert and delete new data in the database table works fine, but when I try to update an existing record, the query somehow deletes the content of other fields in my table row at random.

I have only used the sql `sql = "UPDATE xxx SET name='$name' WHERE id='$id";` etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1 line of code doesn't quite make the cut, and the missing db schema

Comment: @Barista kindly add more code here makes us easy to solve your problem

Comment: There's no way that query can update other field, unless you have a trigger that does it.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an issue with your SQL.

This:   `sql = "UPDATE xxx SET name='$name' WHERE id='$id"`

Should be: `sql = "UPDATE xxx SET name='$name' WHERE id = $id" <=== no quote before id`

Integer values should not have quotes around them.

Either that or: `sql = "UPDATE xxx SET name='$name' WHERE id = '$id'"`, if your id column is not an integer

Comment: This must be a copying error, because otherwise the query won't run at all. It can't update other fields because of that.

Comment: So, you don't have a quote before $id in your code? Unfortunately, there's a limit to what we can do with what you've supplied us with, in this case: a single line of code.

Comment: How should I know, I'm not the OP? But it should be obvious to anyone that this error won't cause **deletes the content of other fields in my table row at random.**

Comment: Sure it could, an UPDATE without a WHERE clause would end up updating the entire table. So, it's logical that there's something wrong with the WHERE clause in the sql that the OP has used, and with what he/she has supplied here, that's the one error anyone could point to.

Comment: He said it's updating random **columns**, not other rows. And he's not missing the `WHERE` clause, he's missing a quote.

Comment: Then again, he's  **new to coding mysqli in general**, so perhaps he doesn't know what he's talking about? :) Frak, okay, you win. :/  :)

Comment: Yes, I am new to this, but miracles do happen :)
I followed all your ideas and thoughts, and made it work. Thank you for this.

However, new strange things happens: Updating a new record once works fine, but if I try to update/correct it again later, some of the text in certain fields in the db row is either deleted or get a lot of spaces added to them. Any ideas why?

Comment: Sure, we're filled to the brim with ideas :) . But if you want the right one, the only way is for us to look at your DB schema and the code you're using to INSERT/UPDATE it.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't close the single quote in the WHERE clause. 
id is an integer value, so you shouldn't need the quotes at all:
`WHERE id=$id`

Comment: That must be a copying error, otherwise the query won't run at all.

Comment: It doesn't delete the content of other fields, it updates them to empty strings. The cause can be passing multiple queries with bad quotes, but from this one line of code, I cannot think of the scenerio that would do that.

Comment: Unless you use `mysqli_multi_query()` it won't let you pass multiple queries.

Comment: Barmar, we don't know what function call your alter ego is using. Echo out your 'sql' variable's content instead of sending it to mysql server, and you should see WHERE the problem is. Barista, I mean. Barista should do this.